Unable to create new .NET Core projects in Visual Studio
In Visual Studio, when attempting to create a new .NET Core project (Web MVC, but the template doesn't seem to be the issue) I get the following error:

One or more errors were encountered while creating project "XXXXX"
The generated project content may be incomplete.
Specified condition "$(EnableNETAnalyzers)" evaluates to "" instead of a boolean.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Analyzers.targets

I've searched looking for an answer as to why this is occurring. It appears to be tied to something in the repo as I can create new solutions and projects in other locations.
Attempting to do a new solution or project in this repo fails. We do have an .editorconfig, but even after removing it and restarting Visual Studio, I still get the above error.
Currently running:
Visual Studio Professional 2022 v17.11.2
.NET 8.0.400
Any and all thoughts or ideas on what might be causing this, would be appreciated!

Hi TChadwick, From official github issues, we found there is known issue inVS 2022 v. 17.11.1. So please upgrade your vs2022 and .net8 sdk to latest version, anc check if it works when create the new asp.net core mvc project.

If you have installed the latest new version(vs2022), please rollback to the previous version, you can find the option in visual studio installer.

You may also be able to narrow down the issue by creating the project via dotnet new mvc command. If it works, it means nothing to do with .net sdk.

After some more exploring, updating VS as recommended in the comments, I identified the root cause of the issue.  In the base of the repo was a "Directory.Build.props" file.  This file contained the following:
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>    
         <Nullable>warnings</Nullable>
        <AnalysisLevel>4.8</AnalysisLevel>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
        <NoWarn>NU1803,CA1014,IDE1006</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

After removing this file, the error went away, and I was able to create new projects without the aforementioned error.  I believe the core issue is with the element <AnalysisLevel>4.8</AnalysisLevel>.  I'm guessing it's tied to the solution being a mixed project (.net framework and .NET Core) and this is analyzing based off .Net Framework 4.8, but that's just conjecture.  I may spend more time later identifying fully that this is the issue, but in the meantime, I've got work to do!
